# generating pdf hangs on rails 4 using PDFkit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-4, wkhtmltopdf

I'm able to download pdf file with:

```
curl google.com | wkhtmltopdf - test.pdf
```

so it means, wkhtmlpdf installation was successful.

But, when I try to generate pdf file by accessing `http://localhost:3000/contacts/1.pdf` it hangs. In the status bar it shows: `Waiting for localhost...`

Rails server output:

```
Started GET "/contacts/1.pdf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-28 21:45:06 +0900
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ContactsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Contact Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered contacts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 99ms (Views: 57.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'pdfkit'
```

application.rb:

```
config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware"
```

According to the [PDFKit railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit) this should be enough for generating pdf files just by adding `.pdf` ...

---

**UPDATE:**

show.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @contact.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Age:</strong>
  <%= @contact.age %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(@contact) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', contacts_path %>
```

layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pdftest</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to @Arman H for helping me to figure out that I have to specify absolute path for assets instead of a relative ones. When I removed the following lines I was able to generate PDF file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Now, I can't get how to substitute this with an **absolute paths**. It seems this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7801102/1745902) is what I need, but I still can't figure out how this would look like for my case.

Comment: How long does it hang for? Do you get any errors from `wkhtmltopdf` in Rails' console? Sometimes it appears to hang, but it's really just taking a long time to process the PDF. How long have you had it running for before cutting the request off?

Comment: The issue above I had on Mac OS x. Now I'm having the same on Linux Mint. It's still "Waiting for localhost..." for 20 min and it seems this is going to be endless. I just have to cancel server by Ctrl + c.

Comment: When I shutdown server after 40 min, it generated pdf file for me. I tried again to shutdown server after 1 min, in this case it showed: command failed: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom 0.75in --margin-left 0.75in --encoding UTF-8 --quiet - -

Comment: Try running `wkhtmltopdf` from terminal, outside of Rails, with the same parameters, and see if it gives you any errors. That is, run `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom`...

Comment: it's also hanging when I run: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom 0.75in --margin-left 0.75in --encoding UTF-8 --quiet - -

Comment: Are you loading assets in HTML (CSS, JavaScript, etc) from the same server that's generating the PDF? I've had similar issues when asset paths were relative, and `wkhtmltopdf` couldn't find/load them. Try removing all assets, and rendering bare HTML. If that's the issue, rewrite your paths with absolute values.

Comment: I've updated my post with show.html.erb and application.html.erb. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34341/discussion-between-arman-h-and-oscar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was due to `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` using relative URLs, which often causes `wkhtmltopdf` to hang when loading assets from the same server that `wkhtmltopdf` is running on.

Using **absolute URLs** for assets solved the problem.

Set `asset_host` in Rails' config, which also affects `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag`:

```ruby
# Modify asset host config setting in `config/application.rb`
# Or create a new initializer: `config/initializers/wkhtmltopdf.rb`
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://mysite.com"

# Or you can have different hosts for development (local) and production (CDN):
# In `config/environments/development.rb`
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost"
# In `config/environments/production.rb`
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net"
```

Comment: Thanks! In the config, which file should I edit? I don't have any host name, I'm running the app localy. What should I specify in this case instead of "http://mysite.com" ?

Comment: Either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` (or whatever local IP you get from Rails console).

Comment: which file should I edit to add config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://mysite.com" ?

Comment: I updated answer. You can set it in either `config/application.rb` or `config/initializers/wkhtmltopdf.rb` (you have to create this file). You can also set different hosts for development/production by assigning different values in `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb` (see update).

Comment: The problem is different, it's because in Rails 4 WEBrick in development env is indeed single threaded. It can't serve images from the localhost anymore. In Rails 3 somehow it worked. Probably by setting the asset_host you indirectly resolved your problem. But the root of it is WEBrick and threads. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027151/how-rails-resolve-multi-requests-at-the-same-time and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377401/pdfkit-hangs-when-generating-a-pdf-with-an-image

Answer (score 3):

Setting `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost"`
in development.rb actually didn't work for me. That is, the PDF generation would work, but then assets wouldn't come through when rendering HTML.

I followed the method here: http://jguimont.com/post/2627758108/pdfkit-and-its-middleware-on-heroku

and it worked like a charm for me. Hope this helps someone. Just throw assets.rb in config/intializers and you're good to go.

Comment: this means locally where ? front or backend ?

Comment: Were you accessing `localhost` from an IP address, or vice versa? That is, perhaps you set `asset_host = "http://localhost"` but were trying to generate via `http://127.0.0.1/my_app/some-route`?

Comment: For images you may use embeded base64 encoded images.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in which my log showed the page had rendered however no pdf was generated and the browser would hang.  It ended up having nothing to do with OS compatability, missing librariers, gems nor dependencies but instead I needed to raise the max allowable thread count for my Puma server (which had been set to 1) upto 2 or more.  This then generated pdf's as normal.