# Rails app hangs when using Wicked_pdf gem and wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to print a PDF of my view by using the `'wicked_pdf' gem. This is the first time I use this gem. I've read the the documentation and googled around and I also found  some simular questions here on Stack Overflow But nothing seems to do the trick.

I've  validated the binaries ( see edit below) they are working fine, so the problem isn´t there.

I found two strange lines in the terminal when running `rails s`( See edit at the bottom)

I've been searching for a solution to this for three straight days, and can't figure this out.

Am I missing something here?

the server constantly hangs with that output in the terminal

```
Rendered pages/partials/_travel_part.html.erb (36.6ms)
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (531.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1640ms (Views: 1115.4ms | ActiveRecord: 136.0ms)
"***************[\"/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf\", \"-q\", \"file:////var/folders/sm/zwm8cy0x73qb6q1pq22r4bjh0000gn/T/wicked_pdf20160913-35465-hkw9b8.html\", \"/var/folders/sm/zwm8cy0x73qb6q1pq22r4bjh0000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20160913-35465-10go9dt.pdf\"]***************"
```

Below is what I have so far.

I want to print `views/users/show.html.erb` so in the `users_controller.rb` I have this code in the `show`method

```
def show

    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @users = User.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)

@paper = current_user.papers.build
@electro = current_user.electros.build
@hwater = current_user.hwaters.build
@cleaning = current_user.cleanings.build
@transport = current_user.transports.build

@papers = current_user.papers

respond_to do |format|
                format.html {render layout:'application'}

               format.pdf {render pdf:"test",javascript_delay:2000,
                layout:'application',template:'users/show.pdf.erb'}
        end
end
```

In the `application.html.erb`I have this in the `head` using the `wicked pdf helper`

```
 <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi"%>
 <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'chartkick'%>

 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

The button in the `views/users/show.html.erb` is

```
 <%= link_to 'Download Pdf', user_path(current_user, format: :pdf) %>
```

in the `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` I have this code

```
 Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

in the `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb` I have this code

```
WickedPdf.config = {
 #:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
 #:layout => "pdf.html",
  :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
 }
```

And in the `gemfile.rb` I have those two gems:

```
 gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.6'
 gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'
```

**EDIT***

Ok I've Validated the binaries are working fine by typing this `wkhtmltopdf google.com    google` in the terminal.  So my conclusion is that the problem lies somewhere else than in the `wkhtmltopdf`. But where? I still can't find out...

```
(AddingWickedPdf) $ wkhtmltopdf google.com    google
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done                                                                      
(AddingWickedPdf) $
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I noticed this lines in the terminal when I started my server `rails s` earlier to night, I don´t know what it means, but I'm sure it has something to do with the App hanging when rendering pdf:

```
/Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
/Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack- 4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of  PDF was here
```

It would be so great if someone could take a look at this and guide me to the right path here.

thanks in advance
DH

Comment: Can you Share you entire action code....

Comment: The question has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was originally posted here:

[How rails resolve multi-requests at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027151/how-rails-resolve-multi-requests-at-the-same-time/20940926#20940926)

Subsequently adapted for this question here (Last answer):

[PDFkit hangs when generating a pdf with an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377401/pdfkit-hangs-when-generating-a-pdf-with-an-image/38246117#38246117)